# Error in sending bytes to Android via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, byte, send

I have a big struggle in sending bytes through Bluetooth in Android, I would make clear that I have watched several tutorial and the Android developers' page.

What my app essentially does is to turn on/off Bluetooth, search devices and connect to them, list the paired devices and also connect to them and it has a control (they are just ImageButtons that send data), I have to activities for when the user searches for a device and for when it wants to see the paired devices so if sending data works on one of them it can work on the other one.

My struggle is on sending the data and it clearly seems that I am doing something wrong in the code. I have saturated the code with toast to know when I do some steps of my app (this toast will be removed once I finish this last step of my app).

And in these saturation I found that my code actually sends the bytes but it does not seems to send them, which is something I do not know how to solve (my code connects to the other Bluetooth device - it even stops flashing its red LED to tell me and the log tell that I am connected to it), I have even copied some code and change it to be part of mine and do what I want it to do.

My XML has all of the necessary permissions.

Code:

```
public class SerachDevices extends ActionBarActivity {

private final BluetoothAdapter BT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

ListView FoundD;
ImageButton btBUp;
ImageButton btBDown;
ImageButton btBLeft;
ImageButton btBRigth;
ImageButton btBStop;


String mensaje;    private ArrayAdapter<String> discoveredDevices;
int Gone = View.GONE;
int Visible = View.VISIBLE;
ConexionABluetooth conectar;


//Metod to find devices
public void Descubrir() {

    BT.startDiscovery();

    if (BT.startDiscovery()) {

        mensaje = "Buscando dispositivos";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        mensaje = "Fallo la busqueda de dispositivos";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


//Reciever for found device
private final BroadcastReceiver FoundDReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

            bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            discoveredDevices.add(bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
        }
    }
};


//Brings up the imageviews, to control the robot
public void btControl(View view) {
    if (!BT.isEnabled()) {

        mensaje = "Activate bluetooth to use control";
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        FoundD.setVisibility(Gone);

        btBUp.setVisibility(Visible);
        btBDown.setVisibility(Visible);
        btBLeft.setVisibility(Visible);
        btBRigth.setVisibility(Visible);
        btBStop.setVisibility(Visible);

    }
}

public void btUp(View view) {
    if(BT.isEnabled()){
        String w = "w";

        conectar.write(w);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        mensaje = "make sure you have \nan active bluetooth connection";
    }

}

public void btDown(View view) {
    if(BT.isEnabled()){
        String s = "s";

        conectar.write(s);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        mensaje = "make sure you have \n" +
                "an active bluetooth connection";
    }
}

public void btLeft(View view) {
    if(BT.isEnabled()){
        String a = "a";

        conectar.write(a);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        mensaje = "make sure you have \n" +
                "an active bluetooth connection";
    }
}

public void btRigth(View view) {
    if(BT.isEnabled()){
        String d = "d";

        conectar.write(d);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), d, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        mensaje = "make sure you have \n" +
                "an active bluetooth connection";
    }
}

public void btStop(View view) {
    if(BT.isEnabled()){
        String q = "q";

        conectar.write(q);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), q, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        mensaje = "make sure you have \n" +
                "an active bluetooth connection";
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(FoundDReciever, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    this.unregisterReceiver(FoundDReciever);
}

//Star onCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_serach_devices);

    btBUp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btUp);
    btBDown = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btDown);
    btBRigth = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btRight);
    btBLeft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btLeft);
    btBStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btStop);


    FoundD = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.btFoundD);
    discoveredDevices = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    Descubrir();

    FoundD.setAdapter(discoveredDevices);

    FoundD.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String itemValue = (String) FoundD.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);

            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = BT.getRemoteDevice(MAC);

            if (BT.isEnabled()) {

                conectar = new ConexionABluetooth(bluetoothDevice);
                conectar.start();


            } else if (!BT.isEnabled()) {

                mensaje = "Bluetooth is not activated";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_serach_devices, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class ConexionABluetooth extends Thread {


    public OutputStream btOutputStream = null;
    private BluetoothDevice btShield;
    public BluetoothSocket mySocket = null;
    private UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    public ConexionABluetooth(BluetoothDevice bluetoothShield) {

        btShield = bluetoothShield;
        try {
            mySocket = btShield.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);

            try {
                BT.cancelDiscovery();
                mySocket.connect();
                try {
                    btOutputStream = mySocket.getOutputStream();
                    mensaje = "Output catched";
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error when getting output Stream");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error with Socket Connection");

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error with Socket Creation");

            try {
                mySocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error Closing socket");
            }
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.d("fail to send", "...In onPause()...");

        if (btOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                btOutputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }


        try {
            mySocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mySocket.close(); //try to close the socket
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
            }
            return;
        }
    }


public void write(String str) {

    try {
        byte[] sd = str.getBytes();
        mensaje = "Message send";
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btOutputStream.write(sd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Writing to Stream", "Error when writing to btOutputStream");
    }
}

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mySocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```